# Windows Phone CPU usage 50% for idle app

Tags: windows-phone-7, cpu-usage

I have an app that use a textbox with textchanged event handler. The problem is if this textbox is focused and app is idle the CPU usage is around 50%. Is there any way of change this CPU usage? is this normal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried and compared to a blank phone app with a single TextBox in it with your event handler added? Have you run the profiler in the SDK on your code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue on another feed. Please, read it, and maybe you'll find some results.

This is the feed...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3ca12e44-c50e-46e5-a7fa-209d20fb2e26/